# Remove DTD from XML SSIS

Tags: ssis, dtd

Hi all im struggling with this one. Ive got a foreach loop that will loop over a folder that contains xml files that i want to import there data into a database. The problem is the xml files have a dtd, theres nothing i can do to prevent this from being attached to the xml file. So i need some way of removing the dtd. Ive searched google and various forums and come up blank. Just wondered if anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a good solution in that im using a script task in my ssis, that opens the file, removes the dtd and then saves the file!!

```
public void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XDoc.Load(Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value.ToString());
                XmlDocumentType XDType = XDoc.DocumentType;
                XDoc.RemoveChild(XDType);
                XDoc.Save(Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value.ToString());
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look for a solution in your preferred programming or scripting language (.NET, Perl, whatever) and then incorporate that into the package. For example, use an Execute Process task to call a command-line tool, or a Script Task that uses the standard .NET XML support.